# Safari 12.1 unload not firing javascript

Tags: javascript, safari, onload

I have javascript in  that is not firing in Safari but works on all other browsers (iOS Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE).

I've tested this on all other browsers (iOS Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE), and this worked on Safari 11.1.

HTML:

body onload="showdiv('Citizenship');"

Javascript:

```
    var pages = document.getElementsByClassName("page");

    function showdiv(id_page) 
    {
        for(var count_page=0; count_page<pages.length; count_page++)
        {
            str_id = pages.item(count_page).id;
            if (id_page == str_id)
            {
                document.getElementById(str_id).style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById(str_id).focus();
            } // if (id_page == str_id)
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(str_id).style.display = 'none';
            } // if (id_page == str_id) else
        } // for(var count_page=0; count_page<pages.length; count_page++)
    } // function showdiv(id_page)
```

I get no console error messages.

The page can be found at http://www.ocetacea.net/MAT/EDLT6616/DigitalCitizenship/index.html

My goal is to have only the "What is Digital Citizenship?" after the page loads.

Comment: What is purpose of this line: `str_id = pages.item(count_page).id;`? Is `pages.item` a function?

Comment: .item() is a method that returns a node at the specified index in a NodeList object.  The NodeList in this case is pages, which I define before the showdiv function.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link to your page. I believe I understand the issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Safari it seems that the body `onload` event triggers after all the content of the page has downloaded.

In your case, you have about 40mb of videos that need to finish loading before Safari triggers body onload action. To fix this, you can trigger your showdiv() function another way, for example:

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if(document.readyState === 'interactive'){
  showdiv('Citizenship');
  }
});
```

Note: This works for me in Safari but I haven't tried other browsers.

Also, you might want to prevent auto-download the videos to save on data transfer costs.